# Find the first occurrence in an array list

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I just wrote below code to find the first occurrence in an array list. Is there any efficient way to do it?

```
function hasName(names, req)
{
  let state = 'pending';

  for(let i in names)
  {
    if(req.indexOf(names[i]) !== -1)
    {
      state = 'init';

      break;
    }
  }

  return state;
}

hasName(['A', 'B', 'C'], ['B', 'D']);
```

Comment: So if any of the items in `names` are found in `req`, you return `'init'`? It would be helpful if you could provide a brief clarification of what's expected. Right now your code is checking for matching items but I don't see that it does anything related to "first occurrence". Generally speaking the easiest way to find the first occurrence of an item in an array is to use something like `Array.find()` or fetch it by index using `Array.indexOf()`

Comment: @TylerRoper That's right. I'm looking for any single item in req that matches with names. First occurrence means the first finded item of req.

Comment: @quirimmo It's working and super simple, Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

names.some(item => req.includes(item))

if it finds any occurrence of the same element in the 2 arrays, returns true, otherwise false

Comment: Good solution but as Tyler said It's better to use more supported native functions like Array.find() and Array.indexOf()

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will work for you

```
const hasName = (names, req) => names.some(name => req.includes(name)) ? 'init' : 'pending';

hasName(['A', 'B', 'C'], ['B', 'D']);
```